# How to apply Lazzy Loading which will work for both UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I am developing an app which uses both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` and both are handling `UIImageView` for displaying an **Image**. but the problem is that, it handles huge amount of data say 1,000 to 50,000 records(**Image** etc) and may increase further.

I wanna put them into background (**Image Downloading** Process). I used so many third party but it will not work for both. So I need to handle it for both controllers which I mentioned above.

I dont want to use a large block of code. because its not possible to put same block every were where I used `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` .

Need to use a short or single line of code to manage it. using only one or two extra files.

Any body has any idea or used this concept then please share it with me.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of API's you used till now?

Comment: use lazy loading with image cache, this should work for both, `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I used Image **cache** _(        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:199.0f];)_. and its working...but I am finding more utilised way for same issue...

Comment: Can you use the SDWebImageCache https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

This problem have so many solutions but its depends on situation...how much data amount of data you are receiving from server. one solution will work and other will not work....

I cant say which condition is exactly matching for your problem. apply **Chache** which u did, try **Buffer** or **Third Party**. because no any other way is remains.

Answer (score 0):

For lazy loading just

1. fetch all the images/media on backgroud thread,
2. store them in cache,
3. and finaly update the UI on main thrad.

Comment: I know that...but I wanna put it on background when it in downloading process....and I want to use block for it....

Comment: @Sarat_Patel for background processing you should use  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //your method for getting images or media 
});